# How to consume output from Tabular Mode in .NET?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas-tabular

I have a local SQL Server in Tabular Mode in which I read data from a local regular SQL Server Database. I have created some Calculated Columns and Fields.
Now I want to use these calculated columns and fields in my "Report Server Project"; how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To query Tabular models from .NET look into using the `AdomdClient` namespace.  The following is a simple example, which sends a DAX command to the Tabular database and returns the results for one measure filtered by the column of one of the dimensions.  Calculated columns can be accessed as they typically would be using this method.

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost;Catalog=YourTabularModel");
conn.Open();
string query = "EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( Employee[Employee Name], \"Employee Count\", "
        + "[Total Employee Count])";

    AdomdCommand modelCmd = new AdomdCommand(query, conn);
    AdomdDataReader dataRdr = modelCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataRdr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataRdr[0].ToString() + " - " + dataRdr[1].ToString());
    }
    dataRdr.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks!
While looking for some information on this method, I found a small tutorial using SSDT: https://www.sqlshack.com/create-simple-ssrs-report-using-ssas-tabular-model-database/